# Centroid calculation for a connected component in 3D volume using Matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, centroid, connected-components

I am trying to implement brain tumor segmentation on 3D brain MRI(.mha data type).

After preliminary segmentation, I am applying 26-neighbor connected component algorithm(using bwconncomp) to obtain the largest connected component by obtaining the component with the largest volume, following which I need to calculate the centroid of the resultant component.

I am not sure if my method of calculating the largest connected component and the centroid is correct, because the centroid obtained and its nearby `voxels` all have value `0`.

Also I am having confusion with the representation of `3D voxel` coordinates. For eg. if `centroid=(x,y,z)`, does it correspond to `x=row`,`y=column` and `z=2D` slice?

Any help would be appreciated. Below is my code with the relevant part.

```
CC=bwconncomp(Ibin,26);  %Input Black & White 3D data of size 240x240x155
Pixelid=regionprops(CC,'PixelIdxList');
[prow pcol]=size(Pixelid);
maxval=numel(Pixelid(1).PixelIdxList);
index=1;
for i=1:prow
 number=numel([Pixelid(i).PixelIdxList]);
 if (number>maxval)  %calculating the component with max number of voxels
  maxval=number;
  index=i;
 end
end
for i=1:prow
 if i~=index
   Ibin(Pixelid(i).PixelIdxList)=0;
 end
end
CC1=bwconncomp(Ibin,26); 
Cent=regionprops(CC1,'Centroid');
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code to the following:

```
CC=bwconncomp(Ibin,26);
PixelIdxList = CC.PixelIdxList;
maxval = numel(PixelIdxList{1});
index = 1;
for ii = 1:length(PixelIdxList)
    number = numel(PixelIdxList{ii});
    if number > maxval
        maxval = number;
        index = ii;
    end
end
[y,x,z] = ind2sub(size(Ibin),PixelIdxList{index})
centroid = [mean(x), mean(y), mean(z)];
```

`bwconncomp` already gives you a `PixelIdxList` so you don't have to use `regionprops`. The `PixelIdxList` lists pixels by their linear indices, so you have to convert them into subscripts to get x, y, and z coordinates. The first dimension in MATLAB matrix represents `y` coordinates, and second dimension represents `x`, while the third dimension represents `z`. Centroid is calculated by taking the mean x, y, and z coordinates of all the pixels contained in the object.